# ¿Por qué openpyxl guarda botón como imagen cuando guardo archivo xlsm?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Tengo un archivo `.xlsm` con una macro programado y un botón que ejecuta dicha macro al hacerle clic.

Lo leo con Python así:

```py
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsm', keep_vba=True)
```

Hago operaciones que no afectan ni a la macro ni al botón y lo guardo así:

```py
workbook.save()
```

El `.xlsm` resultante tiene la macro adecuadamente guardada, pero al hacer clic en el botón no funciona. Este lo toma como una imagen en lugar de como un botón.

¿Sugerencias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resuelto (para mi caso concreto):

El problema era que usaba un botón de control ActiveX en vez de un botón de control de formulario. Por algún motivo el ActiveX da el problema que narro en la pregunta pero el de formulario no. Se puede hacer clic y ejecuta la macro sin problema.